# What should I infer from the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'

Tags: python-3.x, github

I have a python repository, which tries to connect with a database available on web and collect the relevant data. Now when I run the repo from local machine, I get the desired database and hence the output.

However, when I run the same code from the Windows Server and tries to connect the same website(proxy), I am getting the above error.

1. I have installed/uninstalled the respective ODBC driver but no luck
2. Can anyone suggest me any method to get out of this?

```
    (ssf) C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\data-model_1>python main.py
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 612, in <module>
    salesforce_daily_extractors()
    File "main.py", line 44, in salesforce_daily_extractors
    'StartDate': 'StartDate'
    File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\data-model_1\SalesforceExtractor.py", line 23, in __run__ 
    fields = sg.getConnection(sg).__getattr__(sfdc_object).describe()['fields']
    File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\data-model_1\SalesforceGateway.py", line 19, in getConnection
    security_token='************', proxies="*******:8080")
    File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\.conda\envs\ssf\lib\site-packages\simple_salesforce\api.py", line 146, in __init__
  domain=self.domain)
  File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\.conda\envs\ssf\lib\site-packages\simple_salesforce\login.py", line 168, in SalesforceLogin
  proxies=proxies)
  File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\.conda\envs\ssf\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 535, in post
  return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\.conda\envs\ssf\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 479, in request
  prep.url, proxies, stream, verify, cert
  File "C:\Users\admin-prakuma3\.conda\envs\ssf\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 656, in merge_environment_settings
  proxies.setdefault(k, v)
  AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'setdefault'
```

Comment: You should infer that the type of `proxies` is `str`, and not the object which you probably intended it to be.

Comment: @goodvibration Thank you for your reply. I have defined proxies as string

sf = Salesforce(username='****', password='***',
                            security_token='****', proxies="*heree I have defined proxies as string*"